# How to set our settings as a default in JSfiddle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I have an account in jsfiddle.com and I always want to save these setting for default until I change them, for every new fiddle. **And I also want to keep some code in HTML and CSS section**

[image]

But new fiddle always use Mootools.

[image]

Comment: This seems like it belongs on programmers, not here...

Comment: @ChrisMarasti-Georg: There is no reason this should go to Programmers.SE.

Comment: @zzzzBov: This is about a web application, not computer usage. So no point in moving it to Super User. It might be appropriate for Web Apps, though - I'll ask the moderators there.

Comment: I made a chrome extension for this last year: [fiddle config](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fiddle-config/magendaoiemdipeblnllmjhbelpopmgb?hl=en-US).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this yet. There is an open issue that should be resolved in Beta.

https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/44

Comment: zalun himself said this was a good answer on IRC so +1 from me

Answer (score 2):

We'll introduce saving these defaults in the first version of beta. Note that defaults for non-logged in users will **always** be set to MooTools.